# gluLookAt vectors from gyroscope angles

Tags: android, geometry, opengl-es-2.0, gyroscope

Hi I'm trying to rotate the openGL camera using my phone's gyroscope. I am able to get the three angles (X,Y,Z), but I can't find a way to convert them to the direction vectors required by gluLookAt.
The camera is placed at (0,0,0) and should make the same rotations as the phone itself.

Answer (score 0):

gluLookAt needs three vector parameters to calculate correct view matrix. The eye position (in your case (0,0,0)), the center position (where the camera is looking at) and the up vector (where is 'up' direction for the camera).

After choosing initial camera orientation, for many applications the center would be (0,0,1) and up direction (0,1,0). you need to rotate these vectors by desired angle. To do so, you can multiply them with a rotation matrix R = Rx * Rz * Ry where Rx,z,y are rotation matrices along given axes by given angle. If you are using any math package like glm, eigen or similar you can construct these easily. You can even implement them yourself (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).

Note that in case eye position is not (0,0,0), you have to rotate the direction vector, not the center vector. Direction vector = center - eye.

So, a little pseudocode:

```
vec3 eye = .....
vec3 initCenter = .....
vec3 initDirection = initCenter - eye;
vec3 initUp = .....
mat3 rotation = rotate((1,0,0),xAngle) * rotate((0,1,0),yAngle) * rotate((0,0,1),zAngle);
gluLookAt(eye,eye + rotation*initDirection,rotation*initUp)
```

Implementation might look a little different, you might have to use vec4/mat4 as for example glm generates rotation matrices of dimension 4x4.

Comment: I tried rotation matrix but rotations around axes are not commutative and when I rotate the phone 90° the axis "flipped"

Comment: That can happen, it's best to use quaternions in that case.

Comment: OK thank you :) can you please guide me toward a tutorial about quaternions. Also a library to use them would be great ( I'm programming an android app )

Comment: I would suggest http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-17-quaternions/#Quaternions . It has even a section on gluLookAt